# Is there any way to simplify $\sqrt{8\sqrt 6-11}$ (i.e. remove the outer surd)?

Tags: complex-numbers

**Question.** Simplify $\sqrt{8\sqrt 6-11}$, i.e. remove the outer surd.

---

**My Attempt.** I have not done any progress really. I remember my teacher once used complex numbers to do it, but I forgot how he started.

---

**Comment.**

Occasionally, similar problems can be done by completing the square within the outer surd, but here it is testing the approach in general.

Also, the outcome might be messy, but the goal here is to *eliminate such form as surd within surd*.

I just need a hint. Thank you.

Comment: Eh... I doubt it. The minimal polynomial is a quartic, and you can always expect solutions of quartics to be messy.

Comment: Usually, the situation where you would be able to do such a simplification would be if $8^2 \cdot 6 - 11^2$ were a square number.  But in this case, $8^2 \cdot 6 - 11^2 = 263$ is not square.

Comment: This is called "denesting radicals" there's a lot of posts on it.

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot for telling me the technical term. I am looking up on it. @DanielV